# ARRAY ITEMS WITH INCREASING INDEX It's simple and I don't know how

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have this code in my eclipse for developing and android application where i need to have all the items display in my spinner. I manage to have the items displayed in the spinner but the code below is bulky and let's say i have 100 items i will need to have 100 of (item_food[n] +" "+ item_kcal[n] + "kcal")...This can be a basic logic or IQ, but I just don't know how. Is there any function that I can use to replace with the code within {} in the code below? Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
   String[] item_food = res.getStringArray(R.array.items_food);
   String[] item_kcal = res.getStringArray(R.array.items_kcal);
   display = new String[] { (item_food[0]+" " + item_kcal[0] + "kcal"),
            (item_food[1] +" "+ item_kcal[1] + "kcal"),
            (item_food[2] +" "+ item_kcal[2] + "kcal"),
            (item_food[3] +" "+ item_kcal[3] + "kcal"),
            (item_food[4] +" "+ item_kcal[4] + "kcal"),
            (item_food[5] +" "+ item_kcal[5] + "kcal") };
```

Comment: have a look at [loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)... Wait... You already added that tag an array tutorial then: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: it should be looks something like this                                              String[] display=new String[100];
for(int loopCount=0,length=display.length; loopCount<length;loopCount++){
display[loopCount]=(item_food[loopCount] +" "+ item_kcal[loopCount] + "kcal"); 
}                                                                                                                           but as fabian mentioned you must learn basic loop syntax.

Comment: Thank you all. My problem solved. I will study well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do it with a loop. First get the length, which is the minimum of your two source arrays length. Then construct a new `String[]` of that length. Finally loop over your two input arrays and assign a new value to the output slot of your array. Something like

```
int len = Math.min(item_food.length, item_kcal.length);
display = new String[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    display[i] = String.format("%s %skcal", item_food[i], item_kcal[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I tried the code and it works fine. I will study well.

Comment: I have another question. I want to get the number extracted out from the string after the string was selected from the spinner, should I use Regex?

        String cal = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
  String str = cal.replaceFirst("(.*\\s)(\\d)(.*)","$2");
  Log.d("ef","str="+str);